# Python List all Files in Subdirectories but exclude some Directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I want to list all `txt` Files in a Directory Structure but exclude some specific folders.

For example I want to get all `txt` Files under

`D:\_Server\<subfolders>\Temp_1\Config\` or

`D:\_Server\<subfolders>\Temp_1\Config\Stat` 
but exclude

`D:\_Server\<subfolders>\Temp_1\Config\Historie\` and

`D:\_Server\<subfolders>\Temp_1\Config\Archive\`

To get all Files I used the following code:

```
glob.glob('D:\\_Server\\**\\Config\\**\\*.olc', recursive=True)
```

This results in a List of all `txt` Files also those in the `Archive` and `Historie` Folder.

Is this possible with the Python `Glob` Module? Or is there a better solution to archive this?

Comment: check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just filter your result list, for example with a list comprehension:

```py
allResults = glob.glob('D:\\_Server\\**\\Config\\**\\*.olc', recursive=True)
filteredResults = [r for r in allResults if not "Archive" in r and not "Historie" in r]
```

Answer (score 8):

you can do this using `os` also:

```
import os
extensions = ('.txt')                                    #extinctions want to search
exclude_directories = set(['exclude_directory_name'])    #directory (only names) want to exclude
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk('/root/path/to/directory'):  #this loop though directies recursively 
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude_directories] # exclude directory if in exclude list 
    for fname in files:
        if(fname.lower().endswith(extensions)): #check for extension 
           fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)   #this generate full directory path for file
           print fpath
```